# Addition between 32 bit unsigned and 32 bit signed numbers

Tags: c

I would like to have the following checks when I add a 32 bit unsigned number to a 32 bit signed number:

1. If the result is negative, set result to 0 [Floor Condition]
2. If the result is >UINT_MAX, set result to UINT_MAX [Saturate Condition]

What would be the cleanest/optimal way to implement this ?

Comment: Either what Oli says or an if matrix to sort out the different cases.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest converting both to a signed 64-bit type, performing the addition, and then performing the checks (potentially with `min`/`max` macros/functions).

Comment: +1 that does sound like the cleanest, unless for some reason 64 bit conversions and math were very expensive... like a slow 8 bit environment.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: Absolutely; I was focusing on "clean"; whether it's efficient is another matter...

Answer (score 1):

```
uint32_t add_sat(uint32_t a, int32_t b) {
    if (b < 0 && a < -(uint32_t)b) return 0;
    if (b > 0 && a + b < a) return UINT32_MAX;
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: To be pedantic, this exhibits UB when `b == -(2^31)`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:  added the explicit cast to make it well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

@OliCharlesworth ... How about this ?

```
unsigned int safe_add(long long a, long long b)
{
  long long int result = (a + b);

  if(result <= 0)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  if(result > UINT_MAX)
  {
    return UINT_MAX;
  }

  return result;
}
```